# How do I test "should not contain" using FsUnit.Xunit?

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit

I am trying to test that a collection does *not* contain a value using `FsUnit.Xunit`.

```ml
open FsUnit.Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``simple test`` () =
  let xs = [ 1; 2; 3 ]

  xs |> should contain 1

  xs |> should not contain 99 // Not real code
```

I have also tried using `not'`.

**How should I write this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap it in parenthesis since it expects a constraint (and not a function). `contain` is a function that expects a value and returns a constraint.

```
 xs |> should not' (contain 99)
```